# How to generate a `link_to` URL passing some custom parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, link-to

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to generate a `link_to` URL passing some custom parameters. That is, having a `articles_path` (www.my_web_site_name.com/articles) I would like to generate something like the following:

```
link_to 'Sample link title', ... # Here I should implement the code
# => 'http://www.my_web_site_name.com/articles?param1=value1&param2=value2&...
```

**How can I code the `link_to` statement "a là Ruby on Rails Way" in order to accomplish that? And what if I would_like to 'link_to' an 'article_path(@article)' by passing some custom parameters?**

Somewhere I have seen to use something like `link_to 'Sample link title', :param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2'` but in this case it isn't involved the named route (the generated URL refers to the current path).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can send those arguments to the path helper, in this case articles_path. Like this:

```
link_to 'Sample link title', articles_path(:param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2')
```

I think that is what you want.

Comment: And what if I would_like to 'link_to' a 'article_path(@article)' by passing some custom parameters?

Comment: That is no problem either: article_path(@article, :param1 => 'value1')